# Sinon withArgs Custom Matcher

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai-http

I'm trying to use a custom matcher to stub a function that executes twice in my test function from my node.js server. The function that I am testing uses `fs.readFileSync()` twice using different parameters. I figured I could use `stub.withArgs()` twice with custom matchers to return different values for both.

```
let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()

before(function(done) {
  let myStub = sandbox.stub(fs, 'readFileSync')
  myStub.withArgs(sinon.match(function (val) { return val.includes('.json')})).returns('some json value')
  myStub.withArgs(sinon.match(function (val) { return val.includes('.py')})).returns('some python value')
})
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm always getting a 400 status code when using `chai-http` to test my rest endpoint whenever I stub `fs.readFileSync()`. My stub implementation seems to prevent the rest endpoint from even executing functions inside the rest endpoint. When the matcher function triggers, I can verify (with logging) that it goes through my `node_modules` to see if there are any `fs.readFileSync()` functions that needs to return an alternate value.

When I run my mocha tests, with some logging inside the custom matcher, I can verify that `node_modules` like `raw-body` have their `fs.readFileSync()` functions stubbed, but shouldn't return alternate values, because the matcher returns `false` (since the parameters don't pass my matcher). But for some reason, none of my `fs.readFileSync()` functions are getting stubbed and are not even getting executed, because my rest endpoint just ends up returning a 400 empty response.

Is there a special way to stub functions like `fs.readFileSync` when testing with `chai-http`? I was able to successfully stub `fs.writeFileSync()` before, but I'm having trouble stubbing `fs.readFileSync()`.

Comment: I think you need to disclose some more code. It's hard to reason about. But there is no special syntax/way to stub those functions, no. P.S. The default `sinon` object _is_ a sandbox, so you can just call `sinon.restore()` after `sinon.stub()`

Answer (score 0):

I can confirmed with this test example that *stub.withArgs()* with sinon *matchers* works.

```
// File test.js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const fs = require('fs');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('readFileSync', () => {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

  before(() => {
    const stub = sandbox.stub(fs, 'readFileSync');
    stub.withArgs(sinon.match(function (val) { return val.includes('.json')})).returns('some json value');
    stub.withArgs(sinon.match(function (val) { return val.includes('.py')})).returns('some python value');
  });

  after(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('json file', () => {
    const test = fs.readFileSync('test.spec.json');
    expect(test).to.equal('some json value');
  });

  it('python file', () => {
    const test = fs.readFileSync('test.spec.py');
    expect(test).to.equal('some python value');
  });

  it('other file', () => {
    const test = fs.readFileSync('test.txt');
    expect(test).to.be.an('undefined');
  });

  it('combine together', () => {
    const test = fs.readFileSync('test.txt.py.json');
    // Why detected as python?
    // Because python defined last.
    expect(test).to.equal('some python value');
  });
});
```

When I run it from terminal using mocha:

```
$ npx mocha test.js


  readFileSync
    ✓ json value
    ✓ python value
    ✓ other value
    ✓ combine together


  4 passing (6ms)
```